# Rotating a vector perpendicular to another?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Suppose I have two unit vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ in 3D space that are perpendicular to each other. (Their dot product is zero.)

I want to rotate the $x$ vector by $\theta$ degrees such that it remains perpendicular to $y$.  That is, I want to rotate $x$ using $y$ as the axis.

What would be the formula to do this and how is it derived?

Comment: You can find the formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations in the paragraph "Rotation matrix from axis and angle".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give you a general formula, where $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are not necessarily unit vectors.

Assume $\Vert\vec x\Vert, \Vert\vec y\Vert \not= 0$ and they are not collinear.
Call the resulting (rotated) vector $\vec x'$.
First, let's get a vector that is perpendicular to $\vec y$. One such vector is $\vec x\times \vec y$, but for convenience, we will consider the vector $\vec z = \frac{\vec x\times \vec y}{\Vert\vec y\Vert}$. Note that $\Vert \vec z \Vert=\Vert \vec x \Vert$.

This vector is perpendicular to $\vec x$ as well. Because $\vec x'$ lies in the same plane as $\vec x$ and $\vec z$, it can be expressed as their linear combination, i.e.

$$\vec x' = \alpha \vec x + \beta \vec z$$
Multiplying (dot product) both sides with $\vec x$, we get

$$\vec x \cdot \vec x' = \alpha \vec x^2 + \beta \vec z \cdot \vec x = \alpha \vec x^2 \tag1$$
We used the fact that $\vec z$ is perpendicular to $\vec x$, making their dot product zero. Because $\Vert \vec x' \Vert = \Vert \vec x \Vert$, we have that $\vec x \cdot \vec x' = \Vert \vec x \Vert^2\cos\theta$. This, combined with $(1)$ gives us $\alpha = \cos\theta$. Using the fact that $\Vert \vec z \Vert = \Vert \vec x \Vert$ it can easily be shown that $\beta=\sin\theta$.

So, your vector is
$$\vec x' = \cos\theta\cdot \vec x + \sin\theta\cdot \vec z$$

Notice that I haven't mentioned in which direction the vector is rotated. I will leave this for you to figure out.

Comment: What happens if *z* has not the same length as *x*?

Comment: @stephanmg z must be of the same length because of the way I defined it. $\Vert\vec z\Vert = \frac{\Vert\vec x\Vert \cdot \Vert\vec y\Vert}{\Vert\vec y\Vert} = \Vert\vec x\Vert$

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. Thanks.